# Extract specific value from HTML using scrapy and css

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="sites-split">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.page1.com/" target="_blank">text 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.page2.com/" target="_blank">text 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.page3.com/" target="_blank">text 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.page4.com/" target="_blank">text 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to extract te links and the text associated to that link, I manage to get the links by doing:

```
response.css("div.sites-split a::attr(href)").getall()
```

But I don't know how to get the text, I tried:

```
response.css("div.sites-split a::attr(target)").getall()
```

But all I get is:

```
['_blank',
 '_blank',
 '_blank',
 '_blank']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're extracting another attribute, but you need text. Try `response.css("div.sites-split a::text").getall()`